# App rotating to landscape left and right, when landscape "right" is explicitly chosen. Xcode 7.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, uiinterfaceorientation

Can someone tell me why this is happening? Is there anywhere else this needs to be defined?

```
//AppDelegate

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    //return NO;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have a comment `//AppDelegate`. The app delegate's `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is never called (and neither are those other methods), so that code has no effect.

Comment: Thats only to show where the code is.  But you just showed me my mistake by making me look further....  Sorry for posting such a stupid mistake.  I also had this in the AppDelegate   - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{}

Comment: It was returning Landscape not LandscapeRight.  Thank you for pointing out my stupidity. Thank you! @matt

Comment: Cool. Feel free to post that as an answer to your own question: perfectly legal on SO (and encouraged). You asked where else could be having an effect on rotation, and you found it!

Answer (score 0):

I found another interface orientation method in my app delegate. Thanks to @matt's comment, which made me take a harder look. It was returning landscape,  changed it to landscape right and everything is fine now.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
if (([window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]]) && (window.rootViewController.presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed == NO)) {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
//return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```